# Create wireless manifest file (.plist Extension) using Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

My client want to use "Installing apps wirelessly" feature.

Using this he can download application directly from my server no need to synchronize his device.
I search on Internet and I got some information, for that I need two files

1. The app (.ipa) file
2. The manifest (.plist) file.

I know how to create (.ipa) file but i have no idea about (.plist) file. 
If any one having idea how to create (.plist) file please share your idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you export your AdHoc archive and check the 'Enterprise distribution' box, the .plist is exported to the same directory with the same name as the ipa. I did this today for the first time, hosted it on my server and it worked.

Check this:
http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/

Comment: I exported it signed sealed delivered and all I got was an ipa file using Xcode 5...

Comment: Haven't tried with Xcode 5 yet, but it should work. did you follow all steps explained on the link?

Comment: Same problem for me as NicolasMiari

Comment: Works with Xcode 5.1.1: .ipa and .plist are created automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I use Betabuilder, you could find it on [github](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder).
Use it with your ipa, and just upload the files created by the app to a web server an you're good to go.